# Can someone explain this Sass For loop syntax - #{$i}

Tags: sass

In the Sass docs, we have this:

```
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
  .item-#{$i} { width: 2em * $i; }
}
```

I understand the loop. But I don't understand where in `.item-#{$i}` why the `$i` variable is encased in `#{}`? Why not just write `$i`?

I've looked around and can't find anywhere that explains this.

Comment: Why don't you try just writing it as `$i` and see what happens?

Comment: If I write `$i`, it just says _Syntax Error: Invalid CSS..._ It doesn't explain the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Interpolation, and is needed when using a variable in a selector or property name. See http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

Comment: Thanks. I thought this must be the case. I just couldn't find any reference to confirm it.